# How do I make forceUpdate() work to re render my WIzard form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-form

Noob question. I have a `WizardForm` that has two submit buttons. It submits data on the third step and then uploads a photo in the fourth step. How do I re render the entire form after photo uploading succeeds? I'm trying to go back to a clean state of the form so that user can proceed with entering data again, like any normal data entry form.

here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import validate from '../middleware/validate';
import { post } from 'axios';
import {BASE_URL} from '../middleware/api';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import WizardForm from './WizardForm';

let WizardFormPhoto = (props) => {
const {handleSubmit, pristine, previousPage, submitting} = props;
const onFormSubmit = (data) => {
    const {reset} = this.props;
    let humanID = localStorage.getItem('humanID');
    let token =localStorage.getItem('idToken');
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(token);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('humanId', humanID);
    formData.append('photo', data.profile_pic[0]);

    const config = {
        headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization' : AuthStr}
    };
    const url = BASE_URL + 'human/upload';

    post(url, formData, config)
        .then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data.message);
            reset();
            WizardForm.forceUpdate();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)} className="form-horizontal">
        <div className="step-3">
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="col-sm-2 control-label">Add Photo</label>
                <div className="col-sm-10">
                    <Field name="profile_pic" component="input" type="file"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="clearfix">
                <button type="submit" className="next pull-right btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
);
};


export default reduxForm({
form: 'wizard', //                 <------ same form name
forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
validate,
})(WizardFormPhoto);
```

calling `foreceUpdate()` gives me the following error `WizardForm__.a.forceUpdate is not a function` . how do I get it to work?

P.S: `WizardForm` is the parent component, if that matters.

Adding `WizardForm`

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
 import {connect} from "react-redux";
 import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
 import WizardFormFirstPage from './WizardFormFirstPage';
 import WizardFormSecondPage from './WizardFormSecondPage';
 import WizardFormPreview from './WizardFormPreview';
 import WizardFormPhoto from './WizardFormThirdPage'
 import {
isSubmitting,
hasSubmitSucceeded,
hasSubmitFailed
} from 'redux-form'

class WizardForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    this.backToOne = this.backToOne.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        page: 1,
    };
}

nextPage() {
    this.setState({page: this.state.page + 1});
}

previousPage() {
    this.setState({page: this.state.page - 1});
}

backToOne() {
    this.setState({page: 1,})
}

render() {
    const {onSubmit} = this.props;
    const {page, submitSucceeded} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {page === 1 && <WizardFormFirstPage onSubmit={this.nextPage}/>}
            {page === 2 &&
            <WizardFormSecondPage
                previousPage={this.previousPage}
                onSubmit={this.nextPage}
            />}
            {page === 3 &&
            <WizardFormPreview
                previousPage={this.previousPage}
                onSubmit={values => {
                    onSubmit(values, () => {
                        this.setState({
                            submitSucceeded: true
                        });
                        this.nextPage()
                    });
                }}
            />}
            {submitSucceeded && page === 4 &&
            <WizardFormPhoto onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
}

WizardForm.propTypes = {
onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

WizardForm = reduxForm({
form: 'wizard',
initialValues: {
    location: {
        latitude: "0.0",
        longitude: "0.0"
    }
    }
})(WizardForm)

WizardForm = connect(
state => ({
    submitting: isSubmitting('wizard')(state),
    submitSucceeded: hasSubmitSucceeded('wizard')(state),
    submitFailed: hasSubmitFailed('wizard')(state)
})
)(WizardForm)

export default WizardForm;
```

Comment: How is WizardForm defined? Is extending React.Component?

Comment: yes. hold on, I'm adding the code.

Comment: It looks like you're calling the function on the class, as if it were static, not the instance of it. In any case, I don't think it should be necessary to call `forceUpdate` on the React component. Updating the data in the Redux store should re-render the component - I don't have enough familiarity with `redux-form` to say for sure why this isn't happening here.

Comment: I was trying to update the `page` state via `backToOne() `, but was unable to do so. it returns `undefined`. That's why I tried to use `forceUpdate()`.

Comment: plus, `onSubmit` on the `WizardFormPhoto ` isn't getting called at all, possibly because I'm not using redux-form's built in object `values` to submit the form.

Comment: have you tried `this.forceUpdate()`?

Comment: yes. doesn't work. nothing in console either, si I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use intializeForm action creator like following?

```html
import { initialize as initializeForm } from 'redux-form';

dispatch(initializeForm('wizard', {}));
```